# Reporting Services 2008 Visibility

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visibility

Using reporting services and trying to hide a field placeholder value when it does not equal "View"  The value is hyperlinked to a subreport and is located in a bordered textbox inside a tablix.  If I use the visibility feature for the text box, I can hide the non-view hyperlinks with an expression, but it hides the entire textbox and the textbox borders go away for that cell--I really want them to remain and just show the empty cell.  If, instead, I try to hide the value on the placeholder level, which does not present the visibility option, and I attempt to evaluate the expression for the placeholder value to Nothing or '' when it is not valued as "View" then I get a hyperlink dash display in the column where I think it's attempting to render an unvalued hyperlink, which I really don't want.  I just want an empty, bordered textbox.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to change the visibility of the textbox value like this

```
IIF(fields(View.value) = 'true' , fields(TextBoxVariable.value), " ")
```

note that `" "` at the end will hide your `dash`

Or you can put a rectangle in the `tablix` cell and set its border, the you can put a textbox inside of the rectangle and change the visibilityof the textbox easily

Answer (score 0):

put you link action on placeholder properties: Action - go to subreport, then put hidden expression on textbox: IIF(Fields!NameFields="View", true, false)

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I recently ran into this same issue.

Remove the expression from the text box properties and add it to the expression box of the *field* (right-click on the field and instead of choosing Text Box Properties>Visibility, choose Expression from the context menu).  This will replace the field with an expression and the border lines will still exist.

Here's what I added to my expression:

```
=IIF(FORMAT(CDATE(Fields!ApprovedDate.Value),"dd-mm-yyyy") > "01-01-1980",Fields!ApprovedDate.Value," ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way to get rid off this hyperlink dash, is to change the font effect of the text-box. Just select Font-tab from text-box properties and from there, click fx-button of Effects and put somethin like this as expression:

=IIF(Fields!YourValueField.Value is nothing, "None", "Underline")